MUI datagrid v7 : issue with using sx in GridToolbarColumnsButton
I am trying to use sx in GridToolbarColumnsButton but I am not able to use sx directly with GridToolbarColumnsButton, so i tried slotProps but it's not working. Please help.
enter image description here
I am trying to use sx in GridToolbarColumnsButton but I am not able to use sx directly with GridToolbarColumnsButton, so i tried slotProps but it's not working. Please help.

If you are not able to use SX then try Style{{}}. it will be help you

You can use sx like below to style your Mui DataGrid Toolbar buttons. I used "@mui/x-data-grid": "^7.2.0". Check this.
slots={{
   toolbar: () => <GridToolbarContainer>
                      <GridToolbarColumnsButton
                           slotProps={{
                                 button: { variant: 'outlined', sx:{backgroundColor:"red"} },
                           }}
                      />
                  </GridToolbarContainer>}}

